# running load testing on selenium and api tests in Visual studio Team Services

Tags: api, selenium, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, load-testing

I am trying to run load tests on my existing selenium web tests and my api(unit) tests. The tests run in Visual studio using load test editor but does not collect all the metrics like response time and requests per seconds. Are there any additional parameters that I need to add to collect all the metrics ?

Comment: Using full graphical clients for load is state of the art as of 1993.  Consider the use of application layer (HTTP) virtual users which are more resource efficient and generate the same requests to the server under test

Comment: Api calls are at http layer. This is a question regarding getting metrics on VSTS load testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

Load testing; how many selenium clients are you running? One or two will not generate much load. First issue to think about; you need load generators and selenium is a poor way to go about this (unless you are running grid headless but still).

So the target server is what, Windows Server 2012? Google *Create a Data Collector Set to Monitor Performance Counters*.

Data collection and analysis of same is your second issue to think about.  People pays loads of money for tools like LoadRunner because they provide load generators and sophisticated data collection of servers, database, WANs and LANS and analysis reports to pinpoint bottlenecks.  Doing this manually is hard and not easily repeatable.  Most folks who start down your path eventually abandon it.  Look into the various load/performance tools to see what works best for you and that you can afford.

Comment: I am already using VSTS. That is Visual studio team services for performance/load testing.